# Separating a single column into 3 columns, keeping original column (R)

Tags: r

I have a unique character column which is in "DD HH:MM" I am trying to separate the column into 3 new *numeric* columns. My issue with the separate function is that is replaces the original column and I can't figure out how to pass multiple criteria through `SEP =`

[image: Sample of an observation in "DD HH:MM" format]

Please note that not every observation has "DD"

My current code looks like this:

```
separate(numeric_report,Planned.Duration..dd.hh.mm., into = c("Planned Days" ,"Planned Hours" , "Planned Minutes"),sep = ":")
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `remove = FALSE` to stop from dropping original columns and you can use pass multiple `sep` argument using `|`.

```
tidyr::separate(data, Planned.Duration..dd.hh.mm., 
                 into = c("Planned Days" ,"Planned Hours" , "Planned Minutes"), 
                 sep = ":|\\s", remove = FALSE, fill = "left", convert = TRUE)


#      Planned.Duration..dd.hh.mm. Planned Days Planned Hours Planned Minutes
#1                        1:03           NA             1               3
#2                     2 00:38            2             0              38
#3                        0:49           NA             0              49
```

**data**

```
data <- data.frame(Planned.Duration..dd.hh.mm. = 
         c('1:03', '2 00:38','0:49'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Your solution is similar to @akrun above, in that the hours and minutes are separated as days and hours and this shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @Scott217 Use `fill = "left"`. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

We can use `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
    separate( Planned.Duration..dd.hh.mm., 
             into = c("Planned Days" ,"Planned Hours" , "Planned Minutes"), 
             sep = "[: ]+", remove = FALSE, fill = "left", convert = TRUE)

#  Planned.Duration..dd.hh.mm. Planned Days Planned Hours Planned Minutes
#1                        1:03           NA             1               3
#2                     2 00:38            2             0              38
#3                        0:49           NA             0              49
```

---

We can also use `extract`

```
data %>% 
    tidyr::extract(Planned.Duration..dd.hh.mm., 
       into = c("Planned Days" ,"Planned Hours" , "Planned Minutes"), 
            "^(\\d+)? ?(\\d+):(\\d+)$", remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE)

#   Planned.Duration..dd.hh.mm. Planned Days Planned Hours Planned Minutes
#1                        1:03           NA             1               3
#2                     2 00:38            2             0              38
#3                        0:49           NA             0              49
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(Planned.Duration..dd.hh.mm. = 
         c('1:03', '2 00:38','0:49'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I apologize, but the proposed solution is not correct, I was mistaken previously. For observation 1:03, this should be 1 Planned Hour and 3 Planned Minutes. Not 1 Planned Day and 3 Planned Hours.

Comment: @Scott217 i updated the answer.  With `extract` you can have more control